# Table Layout arrangement in android

Tags: android, android-layout

how to arrange controls like below image.

[image]

i already tried with below xml code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Device Status"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:textOff="Device Off"
        android:textOn="Device On" />       
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:text="Save"
        android:onClick="onSaveButtonClick"
         />
</TableRow>    
  </TableLayout>
```

but i got result like this (i need some gap between device status and on/off)

[image]

advance thanks

Comment: you need to set layout_gravity in rows as right , and weight as 1..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Device Status"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
        <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:textOff="Device Off"
            android:textOn="Device On"/>       
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" 
        android:gravity="right">
        <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:text="Save"
            android:onClick="onSaveButtonClick"/>
    </TableRow>    
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

replace your layout with this one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip" android:gravity="right" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="Device Status"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:textOff="Device Off"
        android:textOn="Device On" />       
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:text="Save"
        android:onClick="onSaveButtonClick"
         />
</TableRow>    
  </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try for this:

change  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
to     android:layout_width="0dp" and make toggle button gravity to right.